# View dependency on late-binding view - unexpected behavior

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, view, amazon-redshift

**I'm confused about the following behavior of late-binding views in Amazon Redshift.**

I have a table `test`, a late-binding view `test_view` that reads from `test`. I am able to `drop table test` as expected without needing to cascade down to `test_view`.

Once I create a 'normal' view `test_view_2` to read from the late-binding `test_view`, I am unable to drop the `test` table.

It seems like the 'normal' view forces the late-binding view to change back to a 'normal' view, which is not what I would expect.

Is there a way around this? I'd like to:

- Have the ability to refresh tables without cascading to all dependent views
- Have the ability to keep further-downstream views well-defined, to bubble up schema errors at runtime.

#### To replicate:

```
dataeng=# create table test (id integer);
CREATE TABLE
dataeng=# insert into test values (1), (2), (3);
INSERT 0 3
dataeng=# create view test_view as select id from public.test with no schema binding;
CREATE VIEW
dataeng=# select * from test_view;
 id
----
  3
  1
  2
(3 rows)

dataeng=# drop table test;
DROP TABLE
dataeng=# create table test (id integer);
CREATE TABLE
dataeng=# insert into test values (1), (2), (3);
INSERT 0 3
dataeng=# create view test_view_2 as select id from public.test_view;
CREATE VIEW
dataeng=# select * from test_view_2;
 id
----
  2
  1
  3
(3 rows)

dataeng=# drop table test;
ERROR:  cannot drop table test because other objects depend on it
HINT:  Use DROP ... CASCADE to drop the dependent objects too.
dataeng=#
```

Answer (score 2):

It does appear that the 'normal' view's definition does *not* reference the late-binding view, but rather skips all the way down to the underlying table.

So what's happening here is *not* that the late-binding view is becoming a normal view, but rather that the normal view ends up sitting on top of the table despite having been created as selecting from the late-binding view:

```
dataeng=# \d+ test_view
                        View "public.test_view"
 Column | Type | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage | Description
--------+------+-----------+----------+---------+---------+-------------
View definition:
create view test_view as select id from public.test with no schema binding;

dataeng=# \d+ test_view_2
                         View "public.test_view_2"
 Column |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage | Description
--------+---------+-----------+----------+---------+---------+-------------
 id     | integer |           |          |         | plain   |
View definition:
 SELECT test_view.id
   FROM ( SELECT test.id
           FROM test) test_view;

dataeng=#
```

Comment: This is the behaviour I would logically expect. Creating a "normal" view, i.e. one where "with no schema binding" is *not* specified, implies that the view should be schema bound. Binding to another view, which may itself not be schema bound, would not meet this criteria and so the view is bound to the underlying tables instead of any intermediate views.